# In IE native mode insertbefore(documentfragment,null) is not working and document fragment comes as undefined

Tags: javascript, html

```
Documentfragment.appendchild(newrow);
TB.children[0].insertbefore (documentfragment, insertbeforeobject )
```

This code is working fine in IE non native mode but in native mode it says "Undefined argument in insertbefore"

At first I though the second argument has issue but I was wrong

Document fragment isn't working inside insertbefore

If I simply chamge the code to

```
insertbefore(newrow,insertBeforeObject)
```

then it works

PLEASE does someone know as to why documentfragment isn't working inside insertbefore

Comment: That can't be working, because there is no such function `insertbefore`. There's [`insertBefore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore). JavaScript is case-sensitive, so, for instance, your code has `Documentfragment.appendchild(newrow);` and then tries `insertbefore(documentfragment, inserbeforeobject)`, and since `Documentfragment !== documentfragment` that would cause a problem. If your actual code is different from what you've presented here, please [edit] the question.

Comment: Yea in my actual code it is insertBefore I mistyped here

Comment: There is no problem in the syntax or naming I just mistyped them here . The problem is that insertBefore function isn't working with document fragment in IE native mode

Comment: In order to help you most efficiently, we recommend a [mre]. For HTML/JavaScript issues like yours, [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) provides a way for you to share code that reproduces the issue here on Stack Overflow.